# combining low frequency value into single "other" category using pandas

Tags: pandas, replace

I am using this line of code which has the replace method to combine low frequency values in the column

```
psdf['method_name'] = psdf['method_name'].replace(small_categoris, 'Other')
```

The error I am getting is:

```
'to_replace' should be one of str, list, tuple, dict, int, float
```

So I tried to run this line of code before the replace method

```
psdf['layer'] = psdf['layer'].astype("string")
```

Now the column is of type string but the same error still appears. For the context, I am working on pandas api on spark. Also, is there a more efficient way than replace? especially if we want to do the same for more than one column.

Comment: what is small_categoris? what is the datatype?

Comment: small categories is defined as categories whose values occur less than 5%. dtype is object